# How to call a public static member method(PHP Class) through the Shell Script?And what is the "phpr"?

Tags: php, shell

I have read a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function do_export{

      phpr Job_Sync_Third > /tmp/Job_Sync_Topoc.log 2>/dev/null

}

do_export
```

This code is to call the main functin of a class(Job_Sync_Third). I found this class throungh the "grep -rnw -e" command.

The Following is the class:

```
require_once(xxxx);
class Job_Sync_Third
{
         protected $__config = array();
         public function run () {}
         static public function main()
         {
                 $job = new Job_Sync_Third();
                 $job->run();
         }
}
```

The "phpr" calls the static method in the Job_Sync_Third. It is being installed below the "/usr/bin" directory. 
How did it do it in a shell script calls the static member function of the class?And what is the "phpr"? I can't get any  useful information from Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "phpr" maybe is a parser of the author compile.